# Python - serial read and use of regular expressions to group data

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, serial-port, regular-language

I am reading data from the serial line using basic python code. I store that data to a local variable and then use `re.search` to look for specific values. I then group the data using `match.group` which for the most part works well.

My issue is that sometimes I get data from another place in the serial data which is incorrect based on the pattern that I'm looking for. Is there any way I can make this more reliable?

Some snippets from the python function:

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM' + port, 115200, timeout=0, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, 
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, rtscts=0)

data = ser.read(9999)

ser.close()

match =  re.search(r'Result1:({0}).*(\\r\\n)Result2:(\d)(\d)(\\r\\n)Result3:(\d*)'.format(Result1), 
str(data))

Result1= match.group(1)
Result2= match.group(3) + match.group(4)
Result3= (match.group(6))
```

What the serial data looks like when the code executes and returns the expected result:

> Result1:**11111111**(0x11111111)\r\nResult2:**09**\r\nResult3:**1000**\r\nResult4:1\r\nResult5:20
>   Result6:1\r\nResult7:02\r\n[Thats a RF
>   Datagram:141490\r\n\Result1:**11111111**(0x11111111)
>   \r\nResult2:**09**\r\nResult3:**1000**

What the serial data looks like when the code executes and returns the unexpected result:

> Result1:**11111111**(0x11111111)\r\nResult2:**09**\r\nResult3:**1000**\r\nResult4:1\r\nResult5:20
>   Result6:1\r\nResult7:02\r\n[Thats a RF
>   Datagram:141490\r\n\Result1:**22222222**(0x11111111)
>   \r\nResult2:**07**\r\nResult3:**1250**

It looks like the values for `Result2` and/or `Result3` is picked up correctly most of the time but when there are different values on the final line as shown above (example: 07 and 1250), it fails against expected results. I assumed that the `re.search` expression shown above is looking for the results 1-3 in order but it's just not reliable.

Could anyone shed a little light on where I might be going wrong with this one?

Thanks.

Comment: `\r\n`s are most likely CRLF endings, thus, you should replace `\\r\\n` with `\r\n` in the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `.*` in your pattern, which is *greedy*, so it will match as much as possible skipping over `Result6` and 7 until it finds the second `Result2:`.

Use `.*?` instead, which is the non-greedy version which matches as little as possible. See [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: That's great. Thanks for that suggestion. Script now runs reliably. I did look through those regular expression operations a few days ago but didn't pick that one up as a possible fix for my issue. Thanks again and I'll mark this as a solution.